# Warning message on member signup form page

Tags: civicontribute

On our Contributions page for membership signup:  http://www.essp-ny.org/membership-sign-up.html  there is a warning displayed:  "Warning Some of the profile fields cannot be configured for this page."

Any ideas how resolve this?

Comment: Eric - it would help if you could provide more info about your Profile - what sort of fields does it include - are they all 'contact' or are some 'contact' and some used for other entities?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was causing the warning message...one of the fields in the profile being used.  Not sure what is wrong with the field, but disabling the field cleared the warning.

Comment: Sounds like you were mixing the fields in a way that the profile wouldn't deal with - which is pretty much what the warning said - and hence the original comment on this question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places this information might be generated:

1) By your CMS (which is your platform),

2) By CiviCRM - go to Administrator Menu (then, different depending on your version, a submenu), then error & debugging. Hit "Hide all errors" or similar.

It may be worth hiring a consultant to examine why this error occurs though...